# Unable to connect' to device's GATT server using Google Web-blutetooth API

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I am trying to print all the characteristics for my RealME-1 phone wsing Google's web bluetooth API. The code goes like:

```
 navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
  .then(device => {
    log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
    log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
    log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
    log('>device '+device);

   return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(server => {
    log('Getting Service...');
    return server.getPrimaryService(serviceUuid);
  })
  .then(service => {
    log('Getting Characteristic...');
    return service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    log('> Characteristic UUID:  ' + characteristic.uuid);
    log('> Broadcast:            ' + characteristic.properties.broadcast);
    log('> Read:                 ' + characteristic.properties.read);
    log('> Write w/o response:   ' +
      characteristic.properties.writeWithoutResponse);
    log('> Write:                ' + characteristic.properties.write);
    log('> Notify:               ' + characteristic.properties.notify);
    log('> Indicate:             ' + characteristic.properties.indicate);
    log('> Signed Write:         ' +
      characteristic.properties.authenticatedSignedWrites);
    log('> Queued Write:         ' + characteristic.properties.reliableWrite);
    log('> Writable Auxiliaries: ' +
      characteristic.properties.writableAuxiliaries);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
```

However when testing it gets stuck at device.gatt.connect() . Any ides where am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: any one any help ?

Comment: Code looks good to me.
Which platform are you testing this code?

Comment: Windows 10 and mobile phone having Android 8.1.0

Comment: Do you use Chrome Canary on Windows 10?
Do you use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=en on your Android Phone?